# LocalStorage Select disabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo Este diseño 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que estoy tratando de realizar es que los que están `disabled` guardarlos en el `localStorage` y que al refrescar la pagina o cerrar y abrirla nuevamente permanezcan `disabled`

```
    $(function() {
            $('.asignarConteo').on('click', function(e) {
                $('.widthSelect :selected[value!="0"]').closest("tr").each(function() {
                    //console.log(
                    //    $(this).find(".iarticulo").text(),
                    console.log($(this).find(":selected").val());

                    var ar = $(this).find(".iarticulo").text();
                    var usu = $(this).find(":selected").text();
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'http://localhost:3000/AsigUsuarios',
                        method: 'post',
                        //persist: true,
                        //cache: true,
                        data: { idArticulo: ar, Usuario: usu },
                        success: function(res) {
                            console.log(res);
                            console.log('Entro');
                            $(".widthSelect").filter(function() {
                                return this.selectedIndex > 0;
                            }).prop('disabled', true);

                            //SaveLocalStorage
                    //Store in local storage.
                    localStorage.setItem('rowsSelected', 'disabled');
                    //Read from local storage.
                    localStorage.getItem('rowsSelected');
                        }
                    });
                })
            });

        });
```

Comment: Puedes añadir el HTML para que podamos probar? Qué es lo que te falla?

Comment: Lo que estoy tratando de hacer es que me guarde los que estan disabled en el localstorage

Comment: Si, pero no veo en tu codigo nada con `localStorage`. Primero has de probar tú. Y si tienes fallos o problemas preguntar aqui

Comment: Edite como la estaba intentado.